# How to send array with CURL? Should I `urlencode` it?

Tags: php, post, curl, urlencode

When I assign an array of data to be POSTed as a cURL option (via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS), do I need to urlencode that data first or will that be taken care of?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The C implementation of [`curl_setopt`](http://curl.haxx.se/) doesn't seem to URL-encode the text. However, in PHP5, the [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) function returns a query string representation of the array that *is* URL-encoded.

#### Example Usage

```
  $curl_parameters = array(
    'param1' => $param1,
    'param2' => $param2
  );

  $curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/service",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query( $curl_parameters ),
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => 1.0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false
  );

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curl_options );
  $result = curl_exec( $curl );

  curl_close( $curl );
```

Comment: It only says anything about the urlencoded part if your passing a string of data, nothing about if you need to preencode an array.

Comment: Be careful with http_build_query(), when you post a file it'll crumble the '@' sign.

Answer (score 14):

You don't have to urlencode first. However, it is important to realize that passing an array will make cURL send it as `multipart/form-data`, which explains why it is does not need to get urlencoded (by neither you nor cURL), and you need to use an array if you want to upload files. If you `http_build_query()` first (and send it as a string) it will be treated as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: It does not urlencode them, there is no need to since it is getting sent as multipart form.

Comment: I know that, but the spec doesn't say anything about generating an `multipart/form-data` if an Array is passed.

Comment: That's right, the documentation is slacky. I had to figure it out by myself by sniffing the packets and I think it's also somewhere in the comments (@the PHP doc). Since you have to pass an array if you want to upload files, multipart is the only way anyway.

Comment: Despite being an old topic I found this answer helpful. The endpoint I was connecting to only allowed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so I was setting it manually using the headers but then found this answer. Much preferred.

PHP.net added a notice for this but being below the examples lots of people don't see it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-notes

Answer (score 1):

One problem with using an array for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is that you can't have a name-value pair with an empty value.

Comment: I have ran into the same issue, where I have an array which can sometimes by empty, so for when it's empty, it doesn't send the key for that array at all.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array );
```

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array)  );
```

Answer (score -1):

POST data is not added to the URL (like GET) so you don't need to URLencode it.

Comment: wrong, if passed as a string to the curl_setopt function, it needs to be encoded.