# PHP how to use CURL

Tags: php, python, curl

I need to do this command

```
root@debian:~# curl -X PUT -d '{ "date": "2.5.", "order": 2, "prize": 45 }' '[URL]'
```

in PHP (or Python). But I have no idea how to do it. I tried this:

```
$data = '{ "date": "2.5.", "order": 2, "prize": 45 }';
$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
$ch = curl_init([URL]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

But this returns:

```
{ "error" : "Error: No data supplied." }
```

Any idea how to reproduce it in PHP/Python?

Comment: Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: you are doing json_encode on an already json string -> bad syntax and also remove the http_build_query if you are sending a pure json string as POST

Comment: I made changes, but still did not fix problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = "[URL]";

$data = array(
"date" => "2.5.",
"order" => "2",
"prize" => 45
);

$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Wow this worked, you saved my life (and job :D). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call or subprocess.run will do what you need for this, although the output will get dumped to stdout, so you'll also need to redirect it if you want to manipulate the returned data. However, you could also use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), like some other commenters have suggested.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
    subprocess.call(["curl", "-X", "PUT", "-d", '{ "date": "2.5.", "order": 2, "prize": 45 }', '[URL]'], stdout=tmp)
    tmp.seek(0)
    data = tmp.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoridng to the PHP docs,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

`http_build_query` accepts an array or object as the paramater.
Also, `json_encode` returns a string:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

So, you need to change the way you are using them.

Further, using `http_build_query` might be preferable since it url-encodes the given params:

[When POSTing an associative array with cURL, do I need to urlencode the contents first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574242/when-posting-an-associative-array-with-curl-do-i-need-to-urlencode-the-contents)

So you need to pass an array to the `http_build_query` function to make it work:

Example (from above link):

```
  $curl_parameters = array(
    'param1' => $param1,
    'param2' => $param2
  );

  $curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/service",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query( $curl_parameters ),
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => 1.0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false
  );

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curl_options );
  $result = curl_exec( $curl );

  curl_close( $curl );
```