# cURL not returning JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, curl

I need to make a call to a Rest server to which I need to pass this pattern

```
{"expand":"all",
"offset":0,
"limit":100,
"searchColsCriteria":
[
{"value":"577","column":"lookupValues_contextdept","operation":"="},
{"value":"0","column":"snapshot","operation":"="},
{"value":"0","column":"withdrawn","operation":"="},
{"value":"2019","column":"lookupValues_year","operation":">="},
{"value":"2021","column":"lookupValues_year","operation":"<="}
]
}
```

In PHP, I set an array with parameters and pass it to the cURL call

```
$data =  array(
      'offset'              => 0,
      'limit'               => 100,
      'expand'              => 'none',
  'searchColsCriteria'  => '[{\"value\":\"577\",\"column\":\"lookupValues_contextdept\",\"operation\":\"=\"},{\"value\":\"0\",\"column\":\"snapshot\",\"operation\":\"=\"},{\"value\":\"0\",\"column\":\"withdrawn\",\"operation\":\"=\"},{\"value\":\"2019\",\"column\":\"lookupValues_year\",\"operation\":\">=\"},{\"value\":\"2021\",\"column\":\"lookupValues_year\",\"operation\":\"<=\"}]',
      );
 
            $payload = json_encode($data);
            // Interrogo il webserevice con CURL passando i dati in POST
            $ch = curl_init('https://iris.univpm.it/rest/api/v1/public/items/search');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "restadmin:XXXXXXXXX");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

            // Setto HTTP Header per la POST request 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'cache-control: no-cache',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
                
            ); 
            // Submit the POST request
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            // Risposta del server
            /* per debug */
            print_r($result);
            exit;
            curl_close($ch);
```

but I get this error

> Unrecognized field "searchColsCriteria" (class it.cineca.dspace4.rest.search.SearchSolrRestDTO), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "expand", "offset", "solrQuery", "limit", "sortingColsCriteria"]) at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 63] (through reference chain: it.cineca.dspace4.rest.search.SearchSolrRestDTO["searchColsCriteria"])

I can't figure out if I need to format the array in another way. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You made your `searchColsCriteria` a _string_ value, that contains JSON - but that is not what it contains in that first block of example data you have shown.

Comment: Make the whole structure as a php variable and then encode it all once as json at the end. Otherwise, if you write json by hand and then encode the variable containing it, as you're doing now, you end up with that part double-encoded, so that the server cannot understand it (which is what the error is effectively trying to tell you)

Comment: [How to send array with CURL? Should I `urlencode` it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574242/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

`searchColsCriteria` needs to be an array, something like this

```
$data =  array(
    'offset'              => 0,
    'limit'               => 100,
    'expand'              => 'none',
    'searchColsCriteria'  => [
        [
            'value' => 577,
            'column' => 'lookupValues_contextdept',
            ...the rest
        ],
        [
            'value' => 0,
            'column' => 'snapshot',
            ...the rest
        ],
        ...the other values
    ]
);
```