# cURL POST array results in Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I am trying to POST an array of data from one domain to anther using cURL. When I execute the below code I get the error message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I suspect that the array is not correct after "json_decode" or perhaps I am not forming it in the right way in the sending script?

Ultimately I just want to pass an array of values from one domain to another to be inserted into the mysql DB. Naturally once this basic functionality is working I will lockdown the PDO as well as implement tokens.

Here is my sending script

```
<?php

// Create an array of rows to encode, using the field names we want
$array_data = array (
  array("name"=>"TestArr1","desc"=>"one","price"=>100),
  array("name"=>"TestArr2","desc"=>"two","price"=>200),
  array("name"=>"TestArr3","desc"=>"three","price"=>300)
);           
            
// Encode data to a JSON packet
$json_data = json_encode($array_data);  

$ch = curl_init("https://www.receivingdomain.com/test_insert_multiple.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$array_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

?>
```

Here is my receiving script

```
<?php 

 // Retrieve the raw POST data
$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Decode the JSON data into a PHP associative array
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

require ("/home/test/cnct.php");

 /* insert data into DB */
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `category_id`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $row["name"] . "', '" . $row["desc"] . "', '" . $row["price"] . "', '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"; 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);   
        $stmt->execute();
     }
     
  //close the connection
    $stmt = null;
    $conn = null; 

echo json_encode(array("message" => "Products were created."));

?>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: use [prepared statemenst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) that will not only prevent sql injection it solves in most cases such problems.

Comment: In your code it looks like you meant to post JSON, but you're not actually using `$json_data`, you are posting the plain `$array_data` array.  That will work fine, and PHP handles everything for you, you just need to use `$_POST` on the receiving end.  Some simple debugging would have shown you this.

Comment: Why not try a simple search like "*php curl post json*"?  [The first hit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11079135/6089612) is over a decade old and very highly upvoted, and includes code for both sending and recieving ends.  If you just want to POST an array, and don't care about JSON, why not try a simple search like "*php curl post array*"?  You'll get more highly upvoted questions with highly upvoted answers and example code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13596799/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5104607/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/a/574246/6089612 ...

Answer (score -1):

I won't go into detail about everything that should be done differently

```
<?php

// Create an array of rows to encode, using the field names we want
$array_data = array (
  array("name"=>"TestArr1","desc"=>"one","price"=>100),
  array("name"=>"TestArr2","desc"=>"two","price"=>200),
  array("name"=>"TestArr3","desc"=>"three","price"=>300)
);           
            
// Encode data to a JSON packet
$json_data = json_encode($array_data);  

$ch = curl_init("https://www.receivingdomain.com/test_insert_multiple.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//#############################################################
//here  is your first mistake... if you encode into $json_data 
//i suppose you want to send a json string
//but you are sending the original array($array_data):
//#############################################################
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$array_data);


//you need to make your string clean , i use  base64_encode but urlencode can be used too
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,base64_encode($json_data));

//this is for send text/plain raw data
//and you want to send raw data 
//because on the other side you are using php://input
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
//=====================================================================
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

?>
```

on the other side you just need do add base64_decode like this:

```
<?php 

 // Retrieve the raw POST data
$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Decode the JSON data into a PHP associative array
$data = json_decode(base64_decode($jsonData), true);
//....
```